# preprocess unbalanced skewed data

Tags: python, preprocessing

I am trying to find a way to preprocess my data.
The data is as follow:

| study | person_id | energy_1 | energy_2 | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| study_id | A | 2.3 | -1.05 | 1 |
| study_id2 | B | 1.03 | 0.04 | 0 |

Statistically speaking, we can see that for each study, the value of energy_1 and energy_2 brings a lot of value to determine wether the person is 0 or 1 in the y column: We can mostly only use them to make the prediction.
But when we are using the whole dataset and mixing the studies together, the model used (a binary XGBoost classifier) is no longer able to properly predict the label.

Can you give hints on how to  preprocess/transform my data so that the model could react properly independently of the study?

I am aware that XGBoost do not need normalized data.

Comment: what doe you mean by "value of energy_1 and energy_2 brings a lot of value"?

Comment: They have a high predictability power. I edited the post :)

Comment: How do you figure that those features have a lot of predictive power when the predictions they make are inadequate?

Comment: First test I would do is confirm your hypothesis.  You believe that energy_1 and 2 have power for each study. Dave is asking about that above. Separate the data into each study and build a model on each study by itself. Prove your hypothesis. The separate models by study are obviously independent of the study.

Comment: This part has already been done: I created models for the different studies and it works great. But when the data is merged, since the those two variables are not anymore useable. The range of the data differs.

Comment: Are individuals, eg, A, in multiple studies? Do multiple studies test the same thing? There are really well defined and built statistical methods to do this exact kind of analysis. Have you considered them? Check out repeated measures ANOVA

Comment: Persons are not followed through different studies. All the studies measuer the same thing and use the same protocol for measurements, but the population can be somewhat different. To note that the Y is in fact binary and that this is a ground truth: it does not differ from study A or B.
I'll definitely have a look at repeated measures ANOVA. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @DueSouth See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use mixed effects logistic regression here; it was designed and built for things like this. Y is binary here per comment so you can use logistic regression. Energy 1 and 2 should the fixed effects here; we want to know the effect of increasing energy_1 by 10%. The random effects can be person_id and study. Person and study are just a collection of potentially infinite possibilities. We don't care what the "effect" of having person A vs Person B taking the test. By treating them as Random effects, we save degrees of freedom and can estimate the effect of energy better. Finally, note mixed effects logistic regression has a unique interpretation you should know: [https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/mixed-effects-logistic-regression/#:~:text=Mixed%20effects%20logistic%20regression%20is,both%20fixed%20and%20random%20effects](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/mixed-effects-logistic-regression/#:%7E:text=Mixed%20effects%20logistic%20regression%20is,both%20fixed%20and%20random%20effects).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @user70889. 
I'll definitely explore that solution.
In the meantime, I created different models for the different source of data/ different study to prove the point that there is indeed some predictability.